# context over screen while transitioning between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

When its clicked on some cell, DetailViewController will be opened. Problem is that context from DetailViewController is shown while transitioning between controllers.

Picture below presents problem:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg7Er.png)

DetailViewController is called in function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let singleMovie = movieList[indexPath.row]
    
    getSingleMovie(movieId: singleMovie.id, completion: {})

    getDirector(movieId: singleMovie.id, completion: { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        var directorName = ""
        self.creditResponse?.crew.forEach({ singleCredit in
            if singleCredit.knownForDepartment == .directing {
                directorName = singleCredit.name
            }
        })
        guard let safeMovie = self.detailMovie else {return}
        let detailVc = DetailViewController(movie: safeMovie, groups: self.checkGroups(groups: singleMovie.genreIds), director: directorName, movieIndex: indexPath.row)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVc, animated: true)
        
    })
}
```

DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

let movie: Details?
let groupsValue: String?
let directorValue: String?
let movieIndex: Int?
var checkButton: Bool = false
var favoriteButton: Bool = false

let backButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Icon"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

var movieTitleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Quicksand-Bold", size: 40)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

var groupsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Quicksand-Regular", size: 20)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

var directorLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Quicksand-Bold", size: 20)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.text = "Director: "
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

var directorNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Quicksand-Regular", size: 20)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

var descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Quicksand-Regular", size: 20)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

var movieImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return iv
}()

let buttonChecked: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.475, green: 0.729, blue: 0.757, alpha: 1)
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 35, left: 35, bottom: 35, right: 35)
    button.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.475, green: 0.729, blue: 0.757, alpha: 1)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let buttonFavorite: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.475, green: 0.729, blue: 0.757, alpha: 1)
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 35, left: 35, bottom: 35, right: 35)
    button.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.475, green: 0.729, blue: 0.757, alpha: 1)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    setupUI()
}

init(movie:Details, groups: String, director: String, movieIndex: Int) {
    self.movie = movie
    self.groupsValue = groups
    self.directorValue = director
    self.movieIndex = movieIndex
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}

extension DetailViewController{
@objc func backButtonTapped() {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
}

extension DetailViewController {
func setupUI(){
    view.addSubview(movieTitleLabel)
    view.addSubview(groupsLabel)
    view.addSubview(directorLabel)
    view.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
    view.addSubview(directorNameLabel)
    view.addSubview(movieImageView)
    view.addSubview(backButton)
    view.addSubview(buttonChecked)
    view.addSubview(buttonFavorite)
    setupValues()
    setupConstraints()
    setupButtons()
    
}
}

extension DetailViewController {
func setupConstraints(){
    
    let bottomImageConstraint = movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    bottomImageConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    
        movieImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        movieImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        movieImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        bottomImageConstraint,
        movieImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3),
        
        movieTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        movieTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        movieTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        
        groupsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        groupsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        
        directorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: groupsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        directorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        
        directorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: groupsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        directorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        
        directorNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: groupsLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        directorNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: directorLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
        
        descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: directorLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        
        backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        backButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        backButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        backButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        
        buttonFavorite.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        buttonFavorite.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        
        buttonChecked.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        buttonChecked.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonFavorite.trailingAnchor, constant: -50),

    ])
}

func setupValues(){
    
    movieTitleLabel.text = movie?.title
    guard let safeUrl = movie?.posterPath else {return}
    movieImageView.downloadImage(from: safeUrl)
    descriptionLabel.text = movie?.overview
    groupsLabel.text = groupsValue
    directorNameLabel.text = directorValue
}

func setupButtons(){
    
    let checkValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "checkButton\(movieIndex ?? 0)")
    let favoriteValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "favoriteButton\(movieIndex ?? 0)")
    
    if checkValue == true {
        buttonChecked.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill"), for: .normal)
    }
    
    else {
        buttonChecked.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal"), for: .normal)
    }
    
    if favoriteValue == true {
        buttonFavorite.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)
    }
    
    else {
        buttonFavorite.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
    }
}
}

extension DetailViewController{
@objc func checkButtonTapped() {
    checkButton = !checkButton
    
    
    if checkButton == true {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.buttonChecked.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill"), for: .normal)

        }
    }

    else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.buttonChecked.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.seal"), for: .normal)

        }
    }
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(checkButton, forKey: "checkButton\(movieIndex ?? 0)")
    
}

@objc func favoriteButtonTapped() {
    favoriteButton = !favoriteButton
    
    if favoriteButton == true {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.buttonFavorite.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)

        }
    }

    else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.buttonFavorite.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)

        }
    }
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(favoriteButton, forKey: "favoriteButton\(movieIndex ?? 0)")
}
}
```

How to setup animations so it transits normally?
Transition [GIF](https://hnet.com/video-to-gif/viewimage/20210704-06-hnLdu7xqivaLwfk6-jYrT0x-HNET)

Comment: Can you upload a GIF of what you see during the transition? How does it look after the transition has completed?

Comment: Question is edited with GIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `DetailViewController.view` has no `backgroundColor` set (OR it is `.clear`).

Please assign a `backgroundColor` to your view like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // For testing, you may want to set this to something else like `.red` / `.yellow` 
    // This will help you in identifying where the issue is
    self.view.backgroundColor = .black
}
```